# How to extend Validators in custom form validator?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

```
import {AbstractControl, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

export class Form extends Validators{
static required(control: AbstractControl){
return super.required(control) ?
  {required: true} :
  undefined
 }
}
```

when I extend Validators get this error

**TS2417: Class static side 'typeof Form' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Validators'.
The types returned by 'required(...)' are incompatible between these types.
Type '{ required: boolean; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors | null'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors | null'.**

what can i do

Comment: Why are you extending the `Validators` class instead of just making your own validator function per the Angular docs? Just making sure I'm not misunderstanding you.

Comment: Your undefined needs to be null, that’s a given.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to extend Validator to create a custom one.

You only need it to return a ValidatorFn if there is an error, otherwise it returns null. Here is an example:

```js
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * Validator to verify phone numbers
 */
export class PhoneValidator {
  /**
   * Check that the number entered is a valid phone number
   */
  static isValid(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      if (!control.value) {
        return null;
      }
      const str = control.value.toString().replace(/\s/g, '');
      if (str.length === 9 && /^[679][0-9]{8}$/.test(str)) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return { phone: true };
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Then you can use it in a FormGroup like this:

```js
phone: new FormControl(this.user.phone, PhoneValidator.isValid()),
```

And show this error in your html like this:

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.controls.phone.errors?.phone">
  {{ "error.user.invalid.phone" | translate }}
</mat-error>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of extending required validator to check string emptiness. But remember this executes validation two times, to prevent that, you must provide own implementation of required validator instead of using native one.

```
export function enhancedValidator(
  nativeRequiredValidator: (control: AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors | null
): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const validationResult = nativeRequiredValidator(control);
    if (validationResult) {
      return validationResult;
    }

    if (typeof control.value === "string" && control.value.trim().length === 0) {
      return { required: true };
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

and usage e.g. in main.ts before bootstraping module

```
Validators.required = enhancedValidator(Validators.required);
```